# strftime outputs only in English even with setlocale

Tags: php, setlocale

I am executing few lines of PHP code using WAMP stack in my Windows XP localhost.

I am trying to have the date shown in multiple languages. So first I change the locale using setlocale function as below.

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "fr_FR");
```

And when I try to dump the output the value "Friday" is shown in English. The expected result in French.

```
var_dump(strftime("%A", mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 22, 1978)));
```

Even tried the below option.

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "fr_FR.UTF-8");
```

**NOTE:** I am in WAMP Stack in Windows XP. Not tested in any Linux server.

Apache Version : 2.2.22
PHP Version : 5.3.13

Comment: Do you actually have the French locale installed?

Comment: Yes, In my windows XP I have French locale installed. Does WAMP has anything specific to be installed?